# Need a roadmap for a xamarin forms basd app that integrates google maps location tracking

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms

As a unique final year project i intend to add google real-time location tracking to a practical use for a xamarin.forms application (something like uber but in multiplatform xamarin).
I would like to ask recommendations of whether it will be possible or not and how to approach this task as in what to learn for the backend-frontend knowledge i need to make it happen

Comment: This is the wrong site to ask for such advice. Xamarin Forms gives u the opportunity to write code for android, ios and uwp at once, but also lets u code every platform specific feature of said platforms that exists. You have to search for your specific needs.

Comment: I am just a student and xamarin is basically untouched out here if this is not the correct place please show me the correct place to ask it i just want to know how to build up towards my goal and the skills i must learn to accomplish it

Comment: Welcome to SO. Xamarin forms is good for you. You can have back-end on ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements are 100% possible with xamarin.

For working in xamarin.forms you need to focus on the following.
1) XAML - For FrontEnd
2) C#- Business Logic
3) MVVM architecture (ICommand Interface and INotifyPropertyChanged Interface)
4) Google Maps API
5) Databases - SQLite / Redis
6) Knowledge of .NET standard or .Net Framework or .NET Core

Here are some good links for learning
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/get-started/introduction-to-xamarin-forms
https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/dotnet/in-browser-tutorial/1

https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/&ved=2ahUKEwjYh5-an7veAhWXUn0KHbksB-gQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw1nUfVwCJr5aQIMMe16E40A

https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm&ved=2ahUKEwisyc-mn7veAhUXfysKHSRwBsMQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw07M_C9bcF__xpkN4bb9v0J

All the best for project. Contact me for any help.

Comment: Thanks will start on it right away lets hope i can get 0 to app in 2 months